# Grails: using Javax.ws.rs.Client inside runAsync

Tags: grails, executor

I'm doing a get request from my Grails service to a third party service, as shown in the code below. The code works as expected, but sometimes grails fails to make request to third party service, I'm using this to send OTP to my mobile app. How can I make this procedure much more consistent?

I'm using grails executor plugin to make it async call as I don't need to wait for response.

```
 runAsync {
        String url= "<THIRD-PARTY-URL-HERE>"
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        Response response = client.target(url).request().get()
        if (response.getStatus() == 200)
        {
            String res = response.readEntity(String.class)
            println(res)
            client.close()
        }
        else
        {
            println("fail response: "+response.readEntity(String.class))
            client.close()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trying out Rest Client Builder grails plugin, will post the result.

Comment: I guess I have found the problem, but still not 100% sure. The server where I have hosted my grails app have difficulty in connecting with the Third Party Server, throwing connection timed out exception occasionally.

Comment: Your third party api taking more time to respond your call, therefore you getting connection time out, you may increase your server (tomcat) http request timeout time  or check that, why api taking too much time to respond.

Comment: I'm running this on windows server 2012, may be firewall is blocking something, still investigating.